# Get all the Records from GXTGrid

Tags: extjs, gxt

//MyGrid

```
ListStore< PojoSurveyReportApproved> store = new ListStore< PojoSurveyReportApproved>(loader);  
List<ColumnConfig> configs = getSurvey(list);  
cm = new ColumnModel(configs);  
cp = new ContentPanel();    

final Grid< PojoSurveyReportApproved> grid = new Grid< PojoSurveyReportApproved>(store, cm);    
grid.setTitle("ddddddd");     
grid.setBorders(true);     
grid.getAriaSupport().setDescribedBy(toolBar.getId() + "-display");    
cp.removeAll();   
cp.add(grid);
```

This is my Grid, which loads dynamically. whenever it changes, all the records  from the grid should be retrieved, where i can easily export it to Excel.

Just i want is all the records in the grid eighter as an array or list, is there any listener to handle it or any way i can get all the records.

I have tried out in some ways by adding a listener to a store by it does not gives me result

Answer (score 1):

Did you try-
 `store.getAll();` ?

This code takes all the records in the grid and returns as a collection. However, you may need to take another arrayList to use the store values depending on your needs.

Comment: Could you be more specific @R.I.P, something like ArrayList<POJO> lis=store.getAll();

Comment: Here my store is com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.store.ListStore;

Comment: for a listStore of com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.ListStore, the following is the code:

`List<PojoSurveyReportApproved> listFromStore = store.getAll();`

Something similar should be available for your store.